# How to access the content of simple type XML element via XSLT/XPath after transforming it to JSON and back to XML?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML string

```
<Frequency unit="Hz">200</Frequency>
```

which is transformed to this JSON string

```
{"Frequency":{"unit":"Hz","content":200}}
```

by using this code:

```
final String originalXml = "<Frequency unit=\"Hz\">200</Frequency>";
final String jsonString = XML.toJSONObject( originalXml ).toString();
```

Once I transform it back with this code

```
final String xml = XML.toString( new JSONObject( jsonString ) );
```

I get the resulting xml like this:

```
<Frequency>
   <unit>Hz</unit>
   200
</Frequency>
```

The question now is:
How can I access the value '200' via XPath using a XSLT transformation? The goal is, to get "200 Hz" out of the XML.

Currently I'm achieving this as follows: I'm getting the whole content which returns "Hz200". Then I'm getting the content of "unit" and do a substring-after, which is quiet ugly:

```
<xsl:variable name="frequencyUnit" select="/Frequency/unit"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(/Frequency, $frequencyUnit),' ',$frequencyUnit )"/>
```

With that I get the expected result "200 Hz".

I would appreciate any recommendations.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The goal is, to get "200 Hz" out of the XML.

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/Frequency/text())"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="/Frequency/unit"/>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(/Frequency/text()), ' ', /Frequency/unit)"/>
```

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(/Frequency/text()), ' ', /Frequency/unit)"/>` doesn't work for me. But I tried nearly the same, which is working:
`<xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(/Frequency/text()[2]), ' ', /Frequency/unit)"/>`

But I don't understand, why it works with [2]...

Comment: @StefanieMüller My version assumes the stylesheet has a `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction at the top level. This strips out any whitespace-only nodes, so that the text node containing "200" is the first (and only) text node child of `Frequency`. If you leave it out, the whitespace-only node between `<Frequency>` and `<unit>` will be the first  one, and the one you want the second.

Comment: Great, that made it! Thanks a lot!